# Does MPMoviePlayerController fragment memory?

Tags: ipad

I've been struggling with this for weeks now.

On the iPad so 3.2.  Using UIWebView (so internal YTYoutubeView which I assume is an MPMoviePlayer instance) to show Youtube videos embedded.  Whenever I play multiple videos, the app eventually crashes with low memory, even though every time I run this thru Instruments it crashes around 6.5 to 7mb of live bytes.  This certainly shouldn't be a showstopper.

So I thought maybe I just couldn't get movieplayer to work, even in a webview.  I went and downloaded several other apps that play videos using movieplayer, and they ALL crash after a time with low memory warnings.

Is movieplayer fragmenting so that even though Instruments thinks I'm only using 6.5mb of net or live memory, the pointers are all over the "map"?  What else could it be?

When I unload (pop) the controller memory gets freed up every time.  Like I said, I never get over 7mb before a crash.  But I admit whenever the video actually starts playing, the memory usage spikes by about 2mb then memory settles.

I also can't understand why in 2010 with a supposed beefy tablet, etc. we have to even worry about this stuff.

Anyway, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would note that in the current versions (iOS 4.3 and 5) memory seems to be more stable in this case.